# AWS SAM template with multiple MSK topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-msk

I have a Lambda function which tiggers off 3 MSK topics.

I have found I can easily define this dependency in my template.yaml, but only for 1 topic:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
         ...
         MSKEvent:
          Type: MSK
          Properties:
            MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 1
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            Stream: arn:aws:kafka:.....
            Topics:
              - myTopicName
```

If I try to add more topics `sam build` will fail saying my template is invalid. I have tried, and failed, providing my topics in these 2 ways:

```
Topics:
  - myTopicName
  - myTopicName2
  - myTopicName3
```

```
Topics:
  - myTopicName, myTopicName2, myTopicName3
```

**How do I add multiple MSK topics to my SAM template?**

Comment: For sure, please specify how you add the second topic, and what error it's produces

Comment: I tried a comma seperated list, and specifying topics on individual lines. In both cases my template file will be considered invalid by the AWS sam-cli

Comment: Please, show it in the block code

Comment: Looks like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the sam cli or issue in documentation.
But you can just repeat the MSKEvent construct to add the trigger for other topics.

Something like the below code.

```
  TopicConsumerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        MSKEvent:
          Type: MSK
          Properties:
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            Stream: arn:aws:kafka:ap-south-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster/12abcd12-1234-1234-1234-1234abcd1234-1
            Topics:
              - myTopicName              
        MSKEvent2:
          Type: MSK
          Properties:
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            Stream: arn:aws:kafka:ap-south-1:123456789012:cluster/my-cluster/12abcd12-1234-1234-1234-1234abcd1234-1
            Topics:              
              - myTopicName2
      Policies:
      - AWSLambdaMSKExecutionRole
```

Comment: Worked great! I'm an AWS beginner so I did not even realize that 'MSKEvent' was a user defined name